# grunt-contrib-htmlmin how to ignore template tags

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, gruntjs

I'm using grunt-contrib-htmlmin to minify my html in a backbone/underscorejs project, however, when I run grunt-contrib-htmlmin on any underscorejs template that has <%= myvar %>, the task outputs a parse error. Is there a way grunt-contrib-htmlmin can ignore text inside <%= and %>?

Comment: This isn't solving the actual problem with htmlmin, but at least you can change the delimiters from <% to eg. mustache-style {{ myVar }}. Read about "interpolate" setting at: http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#template

Comment: How will changing <% to {{ allow me to use htmlmin on underscorejs templates?

Comment: OP, did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: I didn't. I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you posted this issue, an new feature was introduced into `html-minifier` (which is used by `grunt-contrib-htmlmin`) to [**ignore the interpolation tags**](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/compare/80fadd1b0bf8a3f4c9f13b940a855ec03a4337c3...d36a358d368747b9e86a6ee6ff37dbb55f2500e8) that were causing the problem.

For instance, the following html partial:

```
<div>
    <span><%= variable %></span>
</div>
```

Will now minify to:

```
<div><span><%= variable %></span></div>
```

Before the changes, it would have resulted in an error.

You can try this using the [demo on the website](http://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/) to test it out.  If that works, you can update your project to make use of the new version.

Comment: I guess this answer is basically referring to the `ignoreCustomFragments` option listed in the [html-minifier documentation](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier)

Answer (score 3):

This issue is old but `grunt-contrib-htmlmin` and `html-minifier` can take new options.

As already mentioned by @mckramer, `grunt-contrib-htmlmin` sits on top of `html-minifier` so you are able to add [additional options](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier):

> `customAttrAssign:<value>`
>
> *Arrays of regex'es that allow to support custom attribute assign expressions*
>
> `customAttrSurround:<value>`
>
> *Arrays of regex'es that allow to support custom attribute surround expressions*

### The solution

Example [grunt](/questions/tagged/grunt) configuration (for double braces `{{ }}`):

```
var hbAttrWrapOpen = /\{\{(#|\^)[^}]+\}\}/;
var hbAttrWrapClose = /\{\{\/[^}]+\}\}/;
var hbAttrWrapPair = [hbAttrWrapOpen, hbAttrWrapClose];

htmlmin: {
  blabla: {
    options: {
      ...
      customAttrSurround: [hbAttrWrapPair]
    },
    files: [
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

These are the only limitations according to the [documentation](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/wiki/Minifying-Handlebars-templates):

> ...
>
> *Note that these expressions are used for parsing individual
>   attribute+value pairs, so a single Handlebars expression may not span
>   multiple attributes. For example, the following markup **would not be**
>   recognized:*
>
> ```
> <img src="logo.svg" {{#if logo_title}}alt="{{logo_title}}" title="{{logo_title}}"{{/if}} />
> ```
>
> *Instead, **each attribute must be** individually wrapped:*
>
> ```
> <img src="logo.svg" {{#if logo_title}}alt="{{logo_title}}"{{/if}} {{#if logo_title}}title="{{logo_title}}"{{/if}} />
> ```

That's it, just you keep an eye on your markup and it will work without issues.

Answer (score 2):

Same workaround, except with regexps for Jekyll tags:

```
var jekyllConditionalWrapOpen = /\{\% if[^}]+\%\}/;
var jekyllConditionalWrapClose = /\{\%[^}]+endif \%\}/;
var jekyllConditionalWrapPair = [jekyllConditionalWrapOpen, jekyllConditionalWrapClose];
```