# how to use grunt htmlmin with mustache?

Tags: mustache, grunt-contrib-htmlmin

I am using grunt htmlmin with mustache template, however, it seems not capable with the {{#mustache}} tag. For example,

```
<div class="m-icon {{^notLogin}}J_linkBtn" data-hash="#page=center"{{/notLogin}}{{#notLogin}}J_ShowLoginBox"{{/notLogin}}></div>
```

and I get:

```
<div class="m-icon {{^notLogin}}J_linkBtn" data-hash="#page=center" notlogin notlogin j_showloginbox notlogin>"></div>
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080853/grunt-contrib-htmlmin-how-to-ignore-template-tags?newreg=1a937d008eb74be0bd441282a01636ea), and I added these lines in my Gruntfile:

```
htmlmin: {                                    
  dist: {                                    
    options: {                               
      customAttrSurround: [
        [/\{\{(#|\^)[^}]+\}\}/, /\{\{\/[^}]+\}\}/]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but I got an error saying: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined when running grunt, which would not appear before the changes.

How should I solve this? Thx.