# Grunt htmlmin clean-css breaking my Handlebars code within <style></style> tags

Tags: handlebars.js, grunt-contrib-htmlmin, clean-css

I have `minifyCSS` set to **true** in my Gruntfile.js htmlmin section like so:

```
htmlmin: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true,
            minifyJS: true,
            minifyCSS: true
...
```

But unfortunately, it is now mangling some of my Handlebars code, turning this:

```
<style type="text/css">
{{#each list}}
  .aClassWithBgImage{{@index}}{background-image:url({{images.thumbnailBoxImage}})}
{{/each}}
</style>
```

into this:

```
<style type="text/css">{background-image:url({{images.thumbnailBoxImage}})}</style>
```

...when really what I wanted (was expecting) is this:

```
<style type="text/css">{{#each list}}.aClassWithBgImage{{@index}}{background-image:url({{images.thumbnailBoxImage}})}{{/each}}</style>
```

Any quick fixes for this? Otherwise, I'm sure I can just restructure my code differently

Answer (score 0):

With help from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27605938/923817), I've discovered that there is an `ignoreCustomFragments` option within the [html-minifier documentation](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier). Using it, you can tell htmlmin to skip trying to compress your `{{}}` tags, using code like this in your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
htmlmin: {
    ...
        options: {
            ignoreCustomFragments: [/<%[\s\S]*?%>/, /<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/, /{{[\s\S]*?}}/], //last item in array is the one for Handlebars. The previous 2 items are the default code tags to be ignored, listed in the documentation
            ...
```

So the key part is adding the `/{{[\s\S]*?}}/` RegEx. (You could, of course, just replace the whole `ignoreCustomFragments` array with that one RegEx if you wanted to.) NOTE: You might want to escape the curly braces '{}' in the RegEx, but it seems to work fine without.

**UPDATE**

So actually, the `/{{[\s\S]*?}}/` RegEx seems to leave a space " " in my code... and if I change it to `/{{.*}}/` , the spaces are removed, but some of my CSS styling becomes uncompressed... so for now, I consider these 2 RegExs somewhat of a "half-solution" . I also tried using `customAttrSurround` [as listed in the Wiki](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/wiki/Minifying-Handlebars-templates) but I couldn't even get that code to work at all in my Gruntfile.js .